# How can i make a server folder path opening in file explorer using IE and SharePoint List?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, custom-list, url, formatting

I'm approaching SharePoint just now, i have this List with our actual and running projects, every project has a specific folder address on our server. 
I want to make that folder opening in file explorer everytime the user clicks on it. 
It works with pure HTML code using

> `<a href="file://\\server\folder\subfolder">LINK</a>`

because of Internet Explorer having this function automatically enabled.

With SharePoint seems not working properly, maybe you can help me! 
Here is what i've done until now:

[image: First example]
[image: Second example]

Do i have to use a particular extension or a specific format of the text? let me know.

Answer (score 0):

You could make a

calculated column with the following formula:

```
CONCATENATE("<a href=""\\yourpath\",[Cartella Server],""">",[Cartella Server],"</a>")
```

if you have  Italian regional settings you should use:

```
CONCATENA("<a href=""\\yourpath\";[Cartella Server];""">";],""">",[Cartella Server];"</a>")
```

Mind that the  data type returned by the formula should be NUMBER

Comment: Where should i put that code :)? In the address field?

Comment: You should create a new Column for the link.  You give it a name as usual but you choose calculated formula. In the formula you add the code and flag NUMBER as returned type.

Comment: I get an error saying: One or more column references are not allowed, because the columns are defined as a data type that is not supported in formulas.

Comment: i've just put: CONCATENATE("<a href=""\\srvterm13v\PJ1400067",[Cartella Server],""">",[Cartella Server],"</a>")

Comment: The thing is that [Cartella Server] is a link column. It should be a text column. Is it a problem to make it a text column instead of a link column?

Comment: I will create a proper column for the case called "cartella" and then should be like this, right? CONCATENATE("<a href=""\\srvterm13v\PJ1400067",[cartella],""">",[cartella],"</a>")

Comment: yesthat's right. Let me know

Comment: Sorry not working :) "only number can go in here" is there a more official way :)?